# Object pronoun usage in imperative structure

Tags: objects

Why do we use  object pronouns in this imperative statements and what is the name of this kind of structure conveying kindness, hate and other emotions?:

Kindness: Thank you!, Bless you!

Hate: Damn you!, Kill you!

Comment: Why do you think they are imperatives?

Comment: Because there is an exclamatory mark written at the end.

Comment: What does an exclamatory mark have to do with imperatives?

Comment: The presence of an exclamation point and the lack of an explicit subject are both commonly associated with the imperative mode.  However, "thank you" is indicative and can be interpreted as "[I] thank you" or "[We] thank you".  "Bless you" and "damn you" might be first-person indicative, third-person subjunctive, or even third-person imperative.  Without further context, I have no idea how to interpret "kill you".

Comment: None of your examples are imperatives, which are distinct by having a covert 2nd person subject (_Sit down_). They don't normally have an exclamation mark at the end. And exclamatives normally begin with "what" or "how" (_What a pretty girl she is!_ / _How stupid you are!_). Constructions like _Thank you_, _Bless You_ and _Damn you_ are actually reduced clauses, where the omitted subject is the 1st person pronoun "I" (which can sometimes be added. e.g. _I thank you_). The omission of a subject pronoun like this is called 'ellipsis'.

Comment: An exclamation mark is characteristically used, not with imperatives, but with exclamative clauses, hence its name.

Comment: Other commenters have given the structure names.  As to why we use pronouns in them, well, the sentence structure would be very awkward without them.  "(I) thank you."  would have to become "(I) thank Henry, and  you are the Henry I mean.".

Comment: @BillJ yes, but is there a generic term for this kind of reduced exclamations?  Something like "expletive", although that's generally for negative "swear words".

Comment: @Andrew I'm not aware of a special name for such ellipsis; it's just one kind of "reduction". Btw, they're not necessarily a form of exclamation. For example, if you pass me the salt, and I politely  say "thank you", that is hardly an exclamation - in writing I would not add an exclamation point. But some elliptical main clauses can be, as in "Never seen anything like it"!

Comment: @BillJ Aren't those all derived from subjunctive constructions? For example "Bless you" is from "God bless you" rather than "I bless you", I'm guessing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Imperative Verbs**

Imperative verbs are verbs which create an imperative sentence, i.e. a sentence that gives an order.

> Why do we use object pronouns in this imperative statements
>
> Kindness: Thank you!, Bless you!
>
> Hate: Damn you!, Kill you!

Well firstly these are not all "imperative statements, per the above, an imperative statement issues a command.  Used in the kind sense, the phrase isn't issuing a command.

So what are they?

**Mood**

Mood is the form a verb takes to show how it is to be regarded (e.g., as a fact, a command, a wish, an uncertainty).

- The imperative mood is a verb form which makes a command or a request - "Get out"
- The indicative mood is a verb form which makes a statement or asks a question - "What was that?" or "I saw something"
- The subjunctive mood is the verb form used to express a wish, a suggestion, a command, or a condition that is contrary to fact. "I suggest that you go"

> and what is the name of this kind of structure conveying kindness,
>   hate and other emotions?:

I would suggest that the structure may be indicative mood, it is more of a statement that a command.

Kindness and hate are independent of sentence structure and grammar.  The grammar indicates how the sentence is composed, what is performing the action and what is having the action performed on it.  Kindness versus hate versus emotion do not factor into grammatical constructs.  Even if the structures may fall into the indicative mood category, it still does not mean "mood" in the emotional sense, it means a grammatical indication of mood.